# Issue with API Manager migration from 1.8.0 to 2.1.0: IS migration client 5.1.0 does nothing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am doing a migration from APIM 1.8.0 to APIM 2.1.0 and facing an issue with one of migration tools.
Naturally, I am following the steps described in migration guide: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release

My OS is Windows 7 Enterprise x64, Java - Oracle JDK 7u67, DB - MySQL 5.7, user store - LDAP.

I downloaded WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 Migration Client (`org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.1.0-migration.zip` SHA1: `ece8ff9a33167751268d205293cc1404fbe4c567`) from `docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/50518205/org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.1.0-migration.zip?version=2&modificationDate=1470811755000&api=v2` as described in guide metioned above (step 7).

Then I unzipped it and put necessary DB scripts into directory `APIM_2.1.0_HOME/dbscripts/` (steps 7-a, 7-b) and JAR file into directory `APIM_2.1.0_HOME/repository/components/dropins/` (step 7-c).

After that when I try to migrate Identity and User Store DBs (step 9) using IS migration client starting APIM instance with command

```
wso2server.bat -Dmigrate -DmigrateIdentityDB -Dcomponent=identity
```

it looks like nothing happens.

I've even configured a logger for this client in `APIM_2.1.0_HOME/repository/conf/log4j.properties` as

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.is.migration=DEBUG
```

but only two DEBUG rows appear in logs telling me that migration component activated successfully:

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Server  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS}
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client.internal.ISMigrationServiceComponent} -  Setting RealmService to WSO2 IS Migration component {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client.internal.ISMigrationServiceComponent}
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client.internal.ISMigrationServiceComponent} -  WSO2 IS migration bundle is activated {org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client.internal.ISMigrationServiceComponent}
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 63ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService}
```

Moreover, I looked at the source code of the client at `github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/v5.1.0/modules/migration/migration-5.0.0_to_5.1.0/wso2-is-migration-client`, especially at class `org.wso2.carbon.is.migration.client.internal.ISMigrationServiceComponent` and its method `activate(ComponentContext context)`, which in fact does nothing in contrast to similar class `github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v2.1.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration/wso2-api-migration-client/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/migration/client/internal/APIMMigrationServiceComponent.java` from another migration client, also provided in migration guide mentioned above (step 4).

And finally, I noticed that relevant code was removed in one of the commits: "**removing the migration from pack and adding script changes**" https://github.com/wso2/product-is/pull/362/files#diff-789b1c66c0ca3e073080a2b8e6c27834L49

So, my questions are:

1. Why were those lines of code removed?
2. And the main question is how to trigger migration client properly? What did I do wrong?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the migration document. Documentation is now changed. you will have to do a migration to 2.0.0 from 1.8.0 and then to 2.1.0.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release#8910

Comment: I have just compared the content of IS migration client ZIP archive from the page you have mentioned above against the content from the client mentioned in original post and I think nothing has changed as far as java classes remain the same, the only change is manifest file and `pom.properties` show fresher build date (August 20, 2016 instead of.August 9, 2016). I will try to migrate again with new guide in a couple of weeks, but I don't think the issue will disappear because the client code has not changed.

Comment: I mean the page about [migration to 2.0.0](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release)

Comment: So, looks like this is a correct answer. I have redone the migration according to the new migration guide in two steps: 1.8.0 - 2.0.0 - 2.1.0 and the migration has gone smoothly.